# pivot table and aggregate based on values

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

```
+-----------------+------------+---
|  A          | B          | C    |
+-----------------+------------+---
|  a1         | NULL       | NULL |
|  a2         | NULL       | NULL |
|  NULL       | b1         | NULL |
|  NULL       | b2         | NULL |
|  NULL       | b3         | NULL |
|  NULL       | NULL       | c1   |
+-----------------+------------+---
```

Is there a way to aggregate the table into this using mysql?

```
+-----------------+------------+-
|  A          | B        | C    |
+-----------------+------------+-
|  a1         | b1       | c1   |
|  a2         | b2       | NULL |
|  NULL       | b3       | NULL |
+-----------------+------------+-
```

However, the number of rows depended on not null values in the column in which have the largest number of not null values and the rest columns will follow. Is there a query to make something like this?
PS: This is from pivoting text values.

Comment: Try ORDER BY A IS NULL, A ASC....

Comment: Is there no connection between the data from one row? How is the output generated?

Comment: "Is there a way to aggregate the table into this using mysql?" Not reliable without a column where we can indentify the order like a id column with AUTO_INCREMENT option or a datetime column with on update current_timestamp. Because a SQL table is a unsorted set of data and without ORDER BY the database is free to return the data in anny order..

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a pivot.  You are trying to put lists of things into columns.  That is not a very SQLish thing to do, but you can accomplish it using variables (or `row_number()` in MySQL 8+):

```
select rn, max(a) as a, max(b) as b, max(c) as c
from ((select (@rna := @rna + 1) as rn, a, null as b, null as c
       from t cross join
            (select @rna := 0) params
       where a is not null
      ) union all
      (select (@rnb := @rnb + 1) as rn, null, b, null
       from t cross join
            (select @rnb := 0) params
       where b is not null
      ) union all
      (select (@rnc := @rnc + 1) as rn, null, null, c
       from t cross join
            (select @rnc := 0) params
       where c is not null
      )
     ) t
group by rn
order by rn;
```

Comment: the null values within the subqueries wlll require a column alias like a, b or c otherwise it's a column name duplication.